# Отклонение ввода в ячейку

Tags: google-apps-script

В общем есть код, который делает выпадающий список в зависимости от значения ячейки

```
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Основной лист");

  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Список принтеров");

  var active = ss1.getActiveCell();

  if (active.getColumn() == 12 && active.getRow() > 1){
    var arrayMakers = ss2.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss2.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var index = arrayMakers[0].indexOf(active.getValue())+1;
    Logger.log(arrayMakers[0]);
    Logger.log(index);
    var dataRange = ss2.getRange(2, index, ss2.getLastRow());
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(dataRange).build();
    active.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
```

вопрос в том что, в ячейке где создается правило все равно можно написать что то, можно ли это как то запретить?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте при билде ValidationRule метод [setAllowInvalid(Boolean)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#setAllowInvalid(Boolean)). По умолчанию там стоит true - а Вам необходимо установить false

Comment: Спасибо, добавил перед билд и все работает)